# jstl tag re-use in a jar

Tags: tags, jstl, code-reuse

Quite simple really, not something I have done before, but I must be missing something.

I have a working jstl tag like this - abbreviated below:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ attribute name="path" type="java.lang.Object" rtexprvalue="true" required="true"%>
<%@ attribute name="l10nprefix" type="java.lang.String" required="false"%>
<%@ attribute name="cssClass" type="java.lang.String" required="false"%>
...a bunch of code...
<form:select path="${path}" cssClass="${cssClass}">
...some more of code...
</form:select>
```

And now I want to put in a shared location (thinking a jar) so that I can reference it from various projects. So I can just reference it like any other taglib.

I can see how you would do this is you are writing a java class extending
javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport (and I recall seeing another class mentioned some where). Simple enough to create a *.tld* file in the right place.

**But I cannot see a *standard* way to re-use jstl tag code. Is there one?**

I read somewhere about tomcat compiling jstl tag code to class files.
Presumably I could then reference that generated class from the *.tld* file.
But to find and encapsulate that in a build seems a bit clunky.
Better to re-write all the code in java and be done with, but what happens next time, when it's more complex code.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for "tag file in jar" leads to this [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html), which says:

> Tag files can be packaged in the /META-INF/tags/ directory in a JAR
>   file installed in the /WEB-INF/lib/ directory of the web application.
>   Tags placed here are typically part of a reusable library of tags that
>   can be used easily in any web application.
>
> Tag files bundled in a JAR require a tag library descriptor. Tag files
>   that appear in a JAR but are not defined in a TLD are ignored by the
>   web container.

Note that your tag is a *custom JSP tag*, and not a *JSTL tag*. JSTL is the JSP standard tag library, and your custom tag is not part of this standard library.